# How to fix search in django 2.2

Tags: django

I have the problem with search class in django 2.2.4 i get error 
ValueError at /search/
Cannot use None as a query value
i can understand why get method doesn't work
sorry for my bad English

```py
views.py

class Search(View):
    """Search on movies and categories"""
    def get(self, request):
        search = request.GET.get("search")
        context = Movie.objects.filter(Q(name__icontains=search) |
                                      Q(category__name__icontains=search))
        return render(request, 'movies/movie_list.html', {"movies": context})

urls.py
path("search/", Search.as_view(), name="search_form"),

form
   <form action="{% url 'movies:search_form' %}"  method="get">
      <input name="search " type="search"  value="" placeholder="Search">
                        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you render the page for the first time, it will not have a `search` value. You thus should implement that case as well:

```
class Search(View):
    """Search on movies and categories"""
    def get(self, request):
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        if search is not None:
            context = Movie.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=search) |
                Q(category__name__icontains=search)
            )
        else:
            context = Movie.objects.all()
        return render(request, 'movies/movie_list.html', {'movies': context})
```

The `else` case might be something different, for example `Movie.objects.none()`, to render no movie at all.

The above can probably be implemented with a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview):

```
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

class Search(ListView):
    """Search on movies and categories"""

    template_name = 'movies/movie_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'movies'

    def get_queryset(self):
        search = request.GET.get('search')
        if search is not None:
            return Movie.objects.filter(
                Q(name__icontains=search) |
                Q(category__name__icontains=search)
            )
        else:
            return Movie.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Make change here

```
search = request.GET.get("search")
```

to

```
search = request.GET.get("search", "")
```